# Using second optional scale for chemfig causes bug in ring with circle

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, bugs

I found a bug in chemfig: 
If you use the second optional argument in `\chemfig[][scale=0.5]` the circle in the ring is not resized:

```
\documentclass[captions=tableabove,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{**6(------)}
\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{**5(-----)}

\chemfig[][scale=1.25]{**6(------)} 
\chemfig[][scale=1.25]{**5(-----)}

\chemfig[][scale=1]{**6(------)} 
\chemfig[][scale=1]{**5(-----)} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docu, the first argument is for the tikzpicture, the second only for nodes. So there will be cases where you need to scale both:

```
\documentclass[captions=tableabove,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{**6(------)}

\chemfig[scale=0.75][]{**6(------)}

\chemfig[scale=0.75][scale=0.75]{**6(------)}

\end{document}
```

[image]